# Can't execute php files in wordpress directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, file-permissions

Here is my problem. 
I have a wordpress site, and I'm trying to make a file to migrate data from one database to another. So I have migration.php in wordpress root folder, but when I navigate to that file, I get error 404 Page Not found from Wordpress.
I have tried different .htaccess fixes, but no luck
my .htaccess looks like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: can you post your .htaccess file?

Comment: don't post formatted code blocks into a comment. it's totally illegible/useless. you can edit/modify you question to add it.

Answer (score -1):

It is file permissions or .htaccess settings that may cause that. In addition you should be sure that file is present in real filesystem path.

Comment: File is present and it is at 777.

Comment: Well, try to, temporary, comment your .htaccess lines and then access your script file. example.com/wordpress/thescript.php

Comment: i tried with empty .htaccess but then I got 500 Internal server error

Comment: Access your public_html folder (the root document of your web server) apply this to the .htaccess there and place your script there then access it like example.com/thescript.php

Comment: Found the solution. Actually problem was that my file was at 777. Had to change it to 644 and it works now. Thanks for help